# Error en importacion prestashop 1.7

Tags: importación, prestashop1.7

Quería actualizar los precios de algunos productos importándolos colocando su ID, pero al momento de comenzar el proceso de importación me arroja de inmediato el error que adjunto en la primer imagen, el cual hay una solución  inspeccionando la llamada de AJAX, y realice dicho proceso para averiguar que estaba mal, y en mi caso me mando un error en particular, mas no me arroja de que alguno de mis campos estuviese mal, adjunto imagen sobre el resultado de la inspección a la llamada del AJAX.
Podrían de favor orientarme un poco para mitigar este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues tu código para poder buscar el problema no solo con las imágenes , solo estas mostrando el error pero sin el código es difícil saber donde esta o por que se esta presentando edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Que tal @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO te comento que estoy en prestashop, una tienda en linea, en la cual, en la parte donde me encuentro no hay código, solo paneles ya diseñados que te ayudan a la importación de los productos, la parte de la inspección de la llamada al AJAX la ocupe ya que era una de las soluciones para mitigar el error, es por eso que anexe dicha imagen.

Comment: Es imposible leer el fragmento que pusiste como imagen.

Comment: Que tipo de archivo estas importando ?

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que me dices y lo que leí en **internet** , puedo sugerirte hacer lo siguiente:

Abra las herramientas de desarrollador (en **`Chrome: haga clic derecho / Inspeccionar`** ) y diríjase a la pestaña `"Red"` justo antes de importar.

Allí debería ver todas las solicitudes de **`AJAX`** que **Prestashop** está haciendo "detrás de escena".

Haga clic en iniciar importación y espere a que aparezca el error.

Cuando eso suceda, revise la última solicitud en la lista y busque la pestaña "`Vista previa`" o "`Respuesta`" de la solicitud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí encontraras la razón por la que no estaba funcionando.

Tienes que entrar a la base de código de **Prestashop** y buscar el mensaje de error, si usted no tiene acceso al código tiene que contactar a la persona que lo tiene para dar solución al error.

Comment: Exactamente eso que me muestras es tal cual lo que yo hice, y en mi caso la respuesta a la llamada del AJAX me arroja el que tengo "una ficha de seguridad incorrecta" (la cual adjunto como segunda img) mas no me arroja si alguna de mis casillas o contenido de las mismas este mal, es por eso mi incertidumbre.

Quiero importar un CSV como siempre lo he estado haciendo

Comment: Valida entonces esta URL (https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/237521-solucionado-clave-de-seguridad-no-v%C3%A1lida/)